# Keep first and last element from a character vector in R

Tags: r, vector, character

I have a character vector as shown below and I want only the first and last letter from each value in this vector that should be separated by a dash (-).

```
df <- c("bcdefg", "abc", "bcdefg", "abcd", "abcdefg", "abc", "a")
```

The result should be like this

```
[1] "b-g"  "a-c"   "b-g"  "a-d"    "a-g"    "a-c"     "a"
```

Any code to do this in the R program. I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `sub` using two capture groups.

```
df <- c("bcdefg", "abc", "bcdefg", "abcd", "abcdefg", "abc", "a")

sub('^(.).*(.)$', '\\1-\\2', df)
#[1] "b-g" "a-c" "b-g" "a-d" "a-g" "a-c" "a"
```

`^` refers to start of the string, `$` as end of the string.

Comment: Thank you. This is what exactly I was looking for. The response was so quick. Thanks a lot :)